# small scale positioning system

Tags: arduino, bluetooth

I have previously entered a competition called "robocup juinor australia" for a few year now with increasingly good performance each year, this year we have been sponsored for over 15k which is a big deal considering all of our previous robots were built for approximately $250. anyway this year we are trying to implement a bluetooth system were each robot knows exactly were the other robot is on the field, we are struggling to come up with an idea to do it considering we cant rely on motor rotations or ultrasonic sensors because of other robots blocking/pushing/interfering with our robots. do you guys have any ideas how we could do this?

link to example game for reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YlVk7OHae2M

Comment: Why would you even consider bluetooth?  Some sort of a mesh network protocol would be a much better idea - e.g. zigbee.  Anyway, how 'exact' do you need to be with the positioning?

Answer (score 1):

You might try making ultrasonic transceivers. A master burst is sent out (let's say) 20 times per second. Each robot has a receiver and a transmitter. The first unit, upon receiving a burst sends out a return burst, then stops listening for 40 msec. The second unit, upon receiving a burst waits 10 msec, then sends out a burst and stops listening for 30 msec, etc. This prevents the mobile units from responding to each others' return bursts.

Or, if you want to be a little trickier electronically, use mobile transmitters which transmit at different ultrasonic frequencies, although this will get into more precision than you might be willing to deal with.

Locate receivers and transmitters on top of the units so they don't get blocked, and shape your mobile transmitters and receivers so as to produce an omnidirectional pattern. Use 2 or 3 fixed receivers to get the timing of the returns and calculate position. Note that blockage isn't as big a deal as it is with a simple echo-location scheme, since the receivers are listening for direct transmission rather than reflection. There will be a certain fixed delay for each mobile unit between reception and transmission, but you ought to be able to calibrate that out.

Comment: by " omnidirectional pattern" do u mean 360 degree array?

Comment: That's one way to do it. Another is to have the output beam pointing straight up. Then you make a reflective cone (slope of 45 degrees) with the axis pointing straight down. You mount the cone directly above the transmitter/receiver. Now sound going straight up gets reflected sideways, from the 45 degree angle, in all directions. That is, it spreads in a small angle vertically, but 360 degrees horizontally. You'd need to do something similar with the base units, since they'd need at least a 90 degree horizontal spread.

Comment: Note that this requires the cone to be significantly bigger than the wavelength of the ultrasonic. In the case of 37 kHz, wavelength is about 1/7 of an inch, so a 1 inch cone should probably work, and 2 inches would be better.

Comment: I once had an electronic whiteboard that worked like that. (half) cones of about 3" diameter. Actually it transmitted both ultrasound and infrared from the pen, and so could do one-way ranging from a fairly simple pen.